# Как изменить расположение кнопок на toolbar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

У меня есть Toolbar и я добавил в него кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_attach"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_attachment_2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/attach"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_accept"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_tick"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/accept"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы кнопки оказались слева? Картинка для наглядности:
[image: Картинка]

Comment: Вам нужно все кнопки переместить как Вы задали в вопросе? или же только галочку как указано в ответе @YaPv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы галочка переместилась и находилась с левой стороны, пропиши в коде строки:

```
toolbar = (ToolBar)findviewbyid(R.id.toolbar); //находишь тулбар 
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.....); //помещаешь иконку
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new ...);// вешаешь слушатель на эту иконку и делаешь с ней, что посчитаешь нужным :)
```

Answer (score 1):

**my_toolbar.xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"//кнопки слева
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**my_activity.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Toolbar-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tToolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public final class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private ActionMenuView amvMenu;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tToolbar);
    amvMenu = (ActionMenuView) t.findViewById(R.id.amvMenu);
    amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
      }
    });

    setSupportActionBar(t);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // use amvMenu here
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_activity_menu, amvMenu.getMenu());
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Do your actions here
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный код, но всё же в каком месте здесь непосредственно задано расположение кнопок тулбара слева?

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное внимание, товарищ YaPV уже объяснил

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасильев `android:gravity="center_vertical|start"`